# Paginação C# e mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, select, datagridview

Tenho um form e um datagrid, nesse form estou usando um timer para fazer uma pesquisa no mysql que preenche o datasouce do datagrid, até aqui tudo certo. Agora precisso limitar a quantidade de pesquisa.
Por ex:

```
Select <campos> from tabela limit 0,5
```

Nesse cód sql, o resultado da tabela será do zero avançando 5 posições, agora preciso de um loop que mude inicio para próximo, ou seja **LIMIT 6,5** DEPOIS **LIMIT 10,5** assim até 50 registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma seria guardar a ultima posição pedida e incrementa-la conforme a quantidade de registos pretendida:

```
int numeroDeRegistos = 5;
int totalRegistos = 50;
for(int ultimaPosicao = 0; ultimaPosicao < totalRegistos; ultimaPosicao += numeroRegistos)
{
    // Select <campos> from tabela limit ultimaPosicao,numeroDeRegistos
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela reposta, mas seu código não da certo, pois o faço, não mostra o resultado um a um no datagrid, ele só mostra o ultimo resultado ou seja depois que acaba o laço;

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes seria uma boa oportunidade para editar a sua perguntar e colocar o codigo que tem actualmente. O codigo que coloquei apenas faz o select, nao actualiza `datagridview` nenhuma. Dai, se mostrar o seu codigo posso actualizar a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo pelo seu retorno valeu. Deu tudo certo aqui. Usei seu exemplo, aqui, atualizando limit antes e depois do método que chama o datagrid valeu.